# Connect to a redis server using redis schema URL

Tags: go, redis

I'm trying to connect to a Redis server which is hosted on a url like this.

`redis://h:asdfqwer1234asdf@ec2-111-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:38799`

I have tried to use 2 libraries and none of them is able to connect to the server. I've used [redix.v3](https://github.com/mediocregopher/radix.v3) and [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis).

With `redix.v3` I get panic error when using the above like URL.

On `go-redis` I got an error about there being too many colons in the url and I've tried using this url
`[redis://h:asdfqwer1234asdf@ec2-111-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com]:38799` which was suggested on some post.

Still no luck. Has anyone successfully connected to a Redis server?

> Code and Error for redix.v3

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("running")
    client, err := radix.NewPool("tcp", "redis://h:asdfqwer1234asdf@ec2-111-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:38799", 10)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    var fooVal string
    err = client.Do(radix.Cmd(&fooVal, "SET", "foo", "hello"))
    fmt.Println(err, fooVal)
}
```

Error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x4f2b7e]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/mediocregopher/radix%2ev3.(*Pool).getExisting(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aks/go/src/github.com/mediocregopher/radix.v3/pool.go:365 +0x4e
github.com/mediocregopher/radix%2ev3.(*Pool).get(0x0, 0x40aa78, 0x51afe0, 0x525120)
    /home/aks/go/src/github.com/mediocregopher/radix.v3/pool.go:403 +0x2f
github.com/mediocregopher/radix%2ev3.(*Pool).Do(0x0, 0x7f6478467fd0, 0xc0000e2070, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aks/go/src/github.com/mediocregopher/radix.v3/pool.go:440 +0x37
main.main()
    /home/aks/hello.go:17 +0x19e
exit status 2
```

> Code and error for go-redis

```
client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "redis://h:asdfqwer1234asdf@ec2-111-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:38799",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
    })

// setup eviction policy on the redis client
client.ConfigSet("maxmemory", Config.RedisMaxMemory)
client.ConfigSet("maxmemory-policy", "allkeys-lru")

_, err := client.Ping().Result()

if err != nil {
    log.Println("Redis: failed to connect", err)
} else {
    log.Println("Redis: connected")
}
```

The Error:

```
2018/10/08 10:57:29 Redis: failed to connect dial tcp: address redis://h:asdfqwer1234asdf@ec2-111-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:38799: too many colons in address
```

Comment: Show the code please, with error.

Comment: There is an example in the godoc https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#ParseURL

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [ParseURL](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#ParseURL) function in go-redis

```
opt, _ := redis.ParseURL("redis://:qwerty@localhost:6379")
client := redis.NewClient(opt)
```